# Understanding the meaning of coefficients in a system of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

In a class I have about system of ODE equations and stability. So in this problem I have the following system of differential equations:

$$\frac{dT}{dt}=a_{11}T+a_{12}E\\
\frac{dE}{dt}=a_{21}T+a_{22}E$$

where:

$T$ - is the planetary temperature change and represent the respons of physical environment

$E$ - is the fossil energy use and represent the human-driven socio-economic development

The problem is given in this picture:

[image]

So I have made graphs for every task in a):

1. When $a_{11},a_{12},a_{21},a_{22}$ all are positive

[image]

2. When $a_{11}<0,a_{12}>0,a_{21}=0,a_{22}>0$

[image]

3. When $a_{11}<0,a_{12}=0,a_{21}<0,a_{22}>0$

[image]

The thing I'm struggling with is explaining the meaning of the combinations. I have been looking at that question for several hours. And I don't understand why $a_{22}$ can't be negativ. I have made a plot below where every coefficient is positiv except for $a_{22}$ but I still don't see why $a_{22}$ can't be less than 0.

[image]

Comment: I have done so. So I can determine stability based on the phase portrait, but I thought there might be something else I should explain for the three scenarios based on the graphs I ploted.

Comment: And I don't understand why a12 can't be negative